# The range of variable in double integral

Tags: integration

[image]

[image]

[image]

Should I just insert the v and u instead of x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$1 \leq x \leq \sqrt2 \implies 1 \leq x^2 \leq 2.$$

$$x^2 \leq y \leq 4 - x^2 \implies 2x^2 \leq x^2+y \leq 4 \implies x^2 \leq v = \frac{x^2+y}{2} \leq 2.$$

Together, the above two inequalities yield the bounds $1\leq x^2\leq v\leq 2$, i.e., $1\leq v \leq 2$. We can find bounds on $u$ in a similar manner, which I leave as an exercise for the questioner.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!